# Jquery method doesn't work after creating HTML in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var stringhtml =  $('<div class="row" id="ao-clonedata">' + '<div class="col-lg-12 form-inline ao-content-padding">' + '<div class="col-xs-1 pull-left ao-from-triggers">'+'<a class="add-link ao-minus-color" title="Remove">'+'<i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg"></i></a>'+'<a class="add-link ao-plus-color ao-spacing-icon" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></a>'+'</div> '+'<div class="col-xs-5 dropdown pull-left ao-padding-zero">'+'<button class="btn dropdown-toggle ao-substitute-dropdown  ao-dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">'+'<span class="pull-left" id="ao-substitute-from">Select Value</span><i class="caret pull-right custom-dropdown-caret"></i>'+'</button>'+'<ul class="dropdown-menu ao-substitute-ul-dropdown" aria-labelledby="substituteFrom">'+'<li onclick="ChangeSubstituteStatus(1,'+' "Select Value",'+' this)"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Select Value</a></li>'+'</ul>'+'</div>'+'<div class="col-xs-1">'+'<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg ao-substitute-arrow" id="ao-arrowbutton"></i>'+'</div>'+'<div class="col-xs-5">'+'<div class="form-inline" id="ao-clonetodata">'+'<div class="dropdown ao-substitute-dropdown pull-left">'+'<button class="btn dropdown-toggle ao-substitute-dropdown ao-dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">'+'<span class="pull-left" id="ao-substitute-to">Select Value</span><i class="caret pull-right custom-dropdown-caret"></i>'+'</button>'+' <ul class="dropdown-menu ao-substitute-ul-dropdown" aria-labelledby="substituteTo">'+'<li onclick="ChangeSubstituteToStatus(1, "Select Value", this)"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Select Value</a></li>'+'<li onclick="ChangeSubstituteToStatus(2, "About Time", this)"><a href="javascript:void(0);">About Time</a>'+'</li>'+'</ul>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>');
```

Creating this HTML on click of an initial(X) button, after creating this html,need to clone this html on click of ".ao-plus-color" (which is there in above HTML). so whatever method i wrote for ".ao-plus-color" is not working.

method for ".ao-plus-color" is :

```
$(".ao-plus-color").on('click', function () {
CCounter = $("#ao-clonewrapper > .row").length + 1;
var clonedata = $("#ao-clonedata").clone(true).attr("id", "ao-clonedata" + CCounter).appendTo("#ao-clonewrapper");

CCounter++;

var clonedatalength = $("#ao-clonewrapper > .row").length;
if (clonedatalength > 0) {
    $("#ao-remove-all").show();
} });
```

can any one help me out to solve this? thanks in advance!

Comment: you should bind the event to already created element `ao-plus-color` is also dynamically created try using `document` like `$(document).on('click','.ao-plus-color', function () {`

Comment: oh yup! got it.. thx for the quick response :)

Comment: is it ok now ?can i post it as answer?

Comment: i will post it as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110982/discussion-between-iamsarav-and-guradio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the event to already created element `ao-plus-color` is also dynamically created.Use `document` like

```
$(document).on('click','.ao-plus-color', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elemens:

```
$("body").on('click',".ao-plus-color", function () {
 CCounter = $("#ao-clonewrapper > .row").length + 1;
 var clonedata = $("#ao-clonedata").clone(true).attr("id", "ao-clonedata" +      CCounter).appendTo("#ao-clonewrapper");
 CCounter++;
 var clonedatalength = $("#ao-clonewrapper > .row").length;
 if (clonedatalength > 0) {
  $("#ao-remove-all").show();
 } 
});
```

Comment: @IamSarav: glad it helps :)